# How to use nuget with fsharp on Linux

Tags: linux, f#, mono, nuget

It's my first hours with F#, playing with it on Ubuntu Linux (14.04) but I am lost how to include install dependencies with nuget.  I have `nuget.exe` working fine on Mono and i can `nuget install` packages; they land in my current directory.  But then i can't import or open them from my `example.fs` file.  I tried various options but to no avail.  Do i need to write a project file or use FAKE?  I couldn't find any tutorial which details the minimal necessary steps to setup a simple project.

So what do i need to do to access dependencies i installed with nuget?

Comment: Last time I tried to do this, I ended up using a template makefile from https://github.com/loverdos/fsharp-mono-template .

Comment: "I tried various options but to no avail" is not enough information

Comment: One things is that F# doesn't recurse in subdirectories - if using fsi, you want to use `#I ...`

Comment: sorry, the "i tried various options" was not helpful indeed.  I was struggling with SO's way of rejecting my question in some automatic manner because apparently some keywords were missing or so ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that it is not completely straightforward. The long answer is that you can approach the problem in a few different ways. All the methods I will suggest here use the MSBuild .fsproj projects, so that you can build with `xbuild MyProject.fsproj`. It's worth noting that FAKE scripts tend to use fsproj projects as well, and hand off to xbuild for the actual compilation. The fsharp.org [website](http://fsharp.org/guides/mac-linux-cross-platform/#nuget) has some instructions on bootstrapping NuGet configuration and is a great resource in general.

1. Use MonoDevelop. I recommend building from source. Get a tag from https://github.com/mono/monodevelop, and follow the instructions carefully. Then install the [Nuget plugin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin). Create an F# project and use the interface in MonoDevelop to add NuGet packages to your project. You can then build from the command line or from MonoDevelop.
2. Find an existing project that uses NuGet, gut it, and use the editor of your choice. A heavyweight example is https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold, you can find others around there. Once you have this project downloaded you will be able to see how to edit the `nuget.config` file to adjust your dependencies.
3. A recent project, [Paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/), offers a truly command-line approach to the problem at last. You again need an `.fsproj` skeleton (like [this example](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/FSharp.AutoComplete/test/integration/Test1/Test1.fsproj)), but you can then create a very simple dependencies file. Download the latest release of Paket from Github. Running `mono paket.exe install` will then use this file to fetch the dependencies from NuGet and add them to your `.fsproj` as references.

There is a bit of a bootstrapping problem, but any of these approaches should get you over the initial hump.

Comment: Why not just install Xamarin Studio rather than vanilla MonoDevelop? It will come configured with nuget/mono/fsharp

Comment: Unfortunately Xamarin Studio is only available for Windows and OSX, not Linux.

Comment: For monodevelop 5.x series nuget is preinstalled

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the script you're doing it's difficult to know what the exact problem is. However, the most lightweight way of getting up and running is to create a .fsx file (rather than a .fs) file. You can then reference dlls using #r syntax e.g.

```
#r @"C:\path\to\my\package\myassembly.dll"
```

You can then access code from there as per usual.